# Remove/block/hide links in a form

Tags: php, hyperlink, href

Is it possibble to remove links submitted in a form? ...this is what I currently have:

```
$forbidden = array('<[\w.]+@[\w.]+>', '<\w{3,6}:(?:(?://)|(?:\\\\))[^\s]+>', '#<.*?>([^>]*)</a>#i');
$matches  = array('****', '****', '****');
$post     =  preg_replace($forbidden, $matches, $post);
```

This changes:

```
1) http://somesite.com to ****
2) someemail@someemail.com to ****
3) <a href="http://somesite.com">im spam</a> to <a href="****">im spam</a>
```

The first two are great but the third I really want the html code removed also ...

p.s: I also have a captcha in place but I want to be very strict on what can and can't be posted.

Answer (score 1):

Run it through [`strip_tags`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php)?

```
echo strip_tags($post[2]);
```